# Консультация по новогоднему соревнованию 2022

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Хотел для развлечения/отдыха/праздника ради предложить к Новому году небольшое соревнование — выразить 2022 с помощью цифр и математических операций с как можно меньшим числом цифр. В двух номинациях — только арифметика (+,-,*,/,скобки) и вторая — с разрешенными степенями, радикалами, факториалами и бифакториалами.

Но побоялся — не будет ли расценено как оффтопик?

Хотя, на мой взгляд, это как раз соревнование в первую очередь программистов :)

Что скажете?

---

Предлагаемый конкурс:

Пока некоторые рисуют елочки, предлагаю заняться более умственной работой :)

Новогодний коннкурс на 2022 год (который, кстати, находится как раз посредине между двумя простыми годами — 2017 и 2027).

Задача — представить число 2022 с помощью как можно меньшего количества одинаковых цифр.

Можно использовать скобки, арифметические операции, возведение в степень, квадратный корень, факториал или двойной факториал (напомню, что двойной факториал для нечетного — произведение всех нечетных, не превышающих данное число, для четного — соответственно четных).
Две номинации - только для "скобки, арифметические операции, возведение в степень", и вторая — разрешено всё выше перечисленное.

И еще — то же самое для ряда цифр 1234567890 и 9876543210 - постараться по возможности получить 2022 для всех подпоследовательностей — ну, там, для 1234567, 12345678 и так далее. Ноль не должен быть тривиальным (например, в конце +0)!

Поскольку конкурс чисто развлекательный, пусть победителя определит голосование за ответы. Понятно, что чем меньше цифр использовано — тем круче решение. Не менее важна и эстетика решения.

Чтобы было понятнее, что требуется — вот несколько решений для 2021 года:

```
1-(1+1)*(1-11111)/11
((999+99/9)*(9+9)+9)/9
((9+9)/9)^(99/9)-9-9-9 
((9+9)/9)^(99/9)-sqrt(9)*9
((9-8)*7*6+5)*43
1*2+3+4*(56+7)*8
```

Comment: [Как задавать вопросы / Вопросы-соревнования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf)

Comment: @andreymal Вы к тому, что критерии неясны? Или что это оффтоп? О критериях — да, например, есть решения эстетичные, есть не очень. И это нечеткий критерий. Но это же не жесткое соревнование, а новогоднее развлечение. Фронтэндеры :) елочки рисуют, ну, а бэкэндеры/математики чем хуже? Ну, а если нужен формальный победитель — то по голосам...

Comment: Я просто ссылку кинул, критерий «с как можно меньшим числом цифр» вроде чёткий

Comment: «Фронтэндеры :) елочки рисуют» — вот поэтому у меня накопилось уже 24 отклонённые тревоги на одном вопросе с требованием к модераторам прекратить эту хрень, и ещё 37 сгоревших голосов за закрытие на двух других вопросах

Comment: Не надо ничего удалять.

Comment: ну в этом году фронтэндеры уже ничего не рисуют... видимо 24 тревоги и 37 голосов за закрытие дают свои плоды...

Comment: @МихаилРебров  Михаил, всё [не так уж плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1366974/28748) :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, рад видеть :)

Comment: @МихаилРебров с фронтэндерами в этом году наметился некоторый прогресс. Видимо, ещё пару лет моего бубнения и Alexandr_TT наконец-то научится писать идеально чёткие условия соревнований

Comment: @МихаилРебров а нет, 3 января Alexandr_TT решил по-тихому испортить условия конкурса, вероятно, надеясь, что я уже не замечу. Таки прокатило — я заметил только сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Ну у нас вроде на каждый Новый Год что-то такое делается, так что, устроить можно.

А вот по критериям есть сомнения. Само число 2022 - это всего 4 цифры и в текущем описании не говорится, что нельзя его просто вот так взять и записать. Возможно, надо добавить в условие, что цифры нельзя обединять в числа, тогда тривиальный вариант отваливается, но всё равно есть довольно простая схема из 14 цифр (и 31 символа).

Пулучается, у нас меньше 14 вариантов количеств - что как-то маловато. Может попытаться ввести более хитрую метрику? Чтобы участвовало число операций, число скобок и, возможно, количество разных операций и разных цифр? А ещё можно поумать про другие системы счисления (ну условно, а то в цифрах-то их нет): как-то использовать максимальную цифру в подсчёте очков.

Comment: «на каждый Новый Год что-то такое делается» — с вопиющими нарушениями правил, которые покрываются модераторами и даже лично Николаем.

Comment: Наверное, я плохо выразился... Из единиц — например, (1111-111+11)*(1+1) — что-то в этом духе. (Решение взял заведомо плохое :)) И так - для всех цифр (ну, кроме нулей :)) Еще интересный вариант — из ряда 1234567890 или 9876543210. Критерий — не только количество, но и эстетика, что бы это ни значило... Так что можно просто голосованием. Но смысл? Это же просто развлечение...

Comment: @Harry в таком случае это что-то вроде «используя одну и ту же цифру во всех числах»

Comment: @Harry Очень жаль, но скорее всего не один я знаю где взять лучшие решения этих задач. Ссылки выкладывать не буду, но кто-то просто сжульничает. Может придумать что-то другое?

Comment: @EOF Да? я не знал... А где? тогда, конечно, смысла не имеет...

Comment: @Harry Используя только одну цифру: т.к. 2022 - это 2 * 3 * 337, то нужно просто найти решение для 337 для цифры 2, 3 или 6. Это можно найти [здесь](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03501.pdf). А по поводу 1234567890 и 9876543210, то решение [здесь](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1479.pdf).

Comment: @EOF Это не кратчайшее решение, а для 12345... — там решения только для полного ряда. А какой минимальной части ряда будет достаточно? 1234? 12345? 123456? Или - с завершающим нулем, при условии **нетривиальности**, т.е. что-то типа `+0` — не проходит?

Comment: @Harry, т. е. есть какой-то ряд цифр и надо между ними расставить знаки?

Comment: Знаки, скобки, и т.д. Просто я когда-то этим увлекался, вот и вспомнил детство :) Типа, для 2021 один из вариантов: 2021 = sqrt((4/4+44)^4)-4 — шести четверок достаточно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Модератор, так что, делать, нет?...

Comment: @Harry, думаю, надо сначала с правилами доформулироватья, и можно делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy См. предлагаемый вариант в дополненном вопросе.

Comment: @Harry, пример с 9876543 означает, что можно любой последовательный набор чисел? Или любую арифметическую прогрессию? Запрет тривиального нуля - чтобы нельзя было с 9 цифр забесплатно получить 10?

Comment: @Qwertiy Желательно - но это невозможно :) — записать одной единицей, единицей и двойкой, потом — 123... Ну, у кого-то да получится минимальный набор. Спойлер: минимальный набор точно меньше 8 цифр :) Ладно, наверное, я снимаю свое предложение — слишком много недопониманий, уточнений и т.д. Если захотите — запустите конкурс от своего имени...

Comment: @Harry, зачем? Хорошая ж идея, запускай давай. С цепным вариантом тоже интересно, но я не понял, какое условие продолжения.

Comment: @Qwertiy Во-первых, не вижу ни малейшего энтузиазма, во-вторых, если я запущу — то не смогу сам участвовать: неэтично будет... :) Кстати, нашел свои решения на 2020 год — пятерок потребовалось всего четыре: 5!!*(5!+5!!)-5. А четверок — пять: 4+(4+4)!/(4!-4) :)

Comment: @Harry, как это не видишь энтузиазма? Я всегда за)

Comment: @Qwertiy Делай! :) У меня энтузиазм уже ушел...

Comment: @Harry, кусь! :)

Comment: @Harry "О нас, математиках, говорят как о сухарях". Надо это менять. Готов сделать доброе дело - объявить ваш конкурс, и даже какие-то баллы (250-300 хватит?) отстегнутьб в качестве награды. Единственное условие - вы вне конкурса, у вас было больше времени на подготовку, вам я их не отдам. Если условие годится, вы разрешаете публиковать - какой срок конкурса ставить?

Comment: @Mikhailo Гм, даже как-то неудобно. Вы меня подозреваете в... даже не пойму, в чем. OK, запускайте конкурс. Я в нем не участвую. Или участвую вне конкурса :) Вобщем, на ваших условиях.